# Need guidelines for developing GUI builder tool using ruby-gtk2

Tags: ruby, gtk, ruby-gnome2

I am in process of developing custom GUI generator tool (its new GUI tool like glade) and to achieve that i am using ruby-gtk2. I am a newbie to the world of ruby and gtk, so i need a help in a problem which i am struck regarding adding background image to a widget.

Let me explain in detail, the application (i.e.,GTK::window) has two sections say left section and right section (section can be frames,layouts,panned window or equivalent). Left section has a list of all widgets like Button, Label, CheckBox and so on as images. So user who needs to design the GUI will drag and drop  any widgets from left section to right sections, on dropping to right section it (i.e., widget) should be re-sizable and also draggable across right section.

Currently i am adding all widgets to eventbox so that on drag n drop on right section i will get all the controls of events like drag_start, drag_motion, drag_end etc..But  how can i add an image as background to eventbox, so that i have button image added to eventbox and also handle resize and drag. Concept is user should be able to resize the properties of widget that drops to right section. Need help in implementing this, i know i am missing something to achieve this. Awaiting any suggestions.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you show some sample code. Better yet, provide a minimal but complete starter script so that someone can attempt to duplicate.